# Binomial identity question

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have the following identity:
$$\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r+k}=\binom{m+n}{m+r},$$
and my professor asked us to prove it in two different ways, I managed to do it in a combinatorial way (I know it as committee argument, thinking on a committee of $m+n$ persons and choosing $m+r$).

But for the second way of proving it, I have been struggling, I tried to express it as the factorial definition or use induction, but the algebra becomes too hard, also I tried to use some classic identities as Pascal or Vandermorde, but I don't find the way out. Is there something I am missing? There is another easy way to prove it?

Thanks.

Comment: are you aware of the coefficient extractor method?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Not really

Comment: what is committee argument?

Comment: @MathLover Suppose that you have a group of m+n people, you want to chose a committee of  m+r, instead of thinking in a group of n+m think in two groups, one of m, and one of n. And choose using subcases.